# Where can I get Microsoft Pivot?

Tags: silverlight, browsing

Does anyone know whatever happend to [microsoft live labs pivot](http://www.ted.com/talks/lang/en/gary_flake_is_pivot_a_turning_point_for_web_exploration.html). Where can I download it?

Couldn't find anything on the web. The official site redirects to bing 404 page. Seems like Microsoft has wiped all the traces of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean, Silverlight Pivot Viewer:

http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/pivotviewer/

It's still alive and kicking, although I wouldn't put all my eggs in that particular basket.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it. Though not exactly what I was hoping to find. I guess it's what the original product evolved into.